# Why can a const member function modify an object's mutable data member in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutable

Why and how can a `const` member function modify an object's `mutable` data member?

Member functions use the `this` pointer to modify the data members of an object. The `this` pointer of a `const` member function is a pointer to a constant, not a normal data member. So why is it always possible to modify the data members marked `mutable` of an object, and how does the compiler implement it?

Comment: "_The this pointer of a const member function is a pointer to a constant_": What do you imagine the difference to be between a `const` pointer and a non-`const` pointer from the point of view of the compiler? Also, how do you know that a `const` pointer actually points to a _constant_? You can make a `const` pointer to a non-constant object.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The OP has asked a perfectly legitimate question, IMO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the 'mutable' keyword have any purpose other than allowing the variable to be modified by a const function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/does-the-mutable-keyword-have-any-purpose-other-than-allowing-the-variable-to)

Comment: @BoP I don't see how that question relates to this one. OP is asking about how the `mutable` keyword works, not about all its uses.

Comment: When verbosely declared  `mutable`, a member object will not inherit its owning objects const qualification; It will remain `mutable`.

Answer (score 7):

The entire point of `mutable` member variables is that they can be modified via a `const` instance.  So the fact that `this` is `const` has no relevance when modifying a `mutable` member variable--just as it has no relevance when reading a member variable.

Comment: By default, the this pointer of a regular member function is a const pointer to a nonconstant, while the this pointer of a const member function is a const pointer to a constant. So I wonder if it's because a const member function that accesses the mutable data member accepts both a const pointer to a nonconstant (which accesses the mutable data member) and a const pointer to a constant (which accesses the general data member)?I want to know how it works

Comment: @yxyc-137 "_the this pointer of a const member function is a const pointer to a constant_": Where are you getting this from? A `const` pointer doesn't have to point to a constant object: `int i; const int* ptr = &i;`, `i` is not a constant object, but `ptr` is a `const` pointer to it. And indeed a `mutable` subobject is _never_ a constant object, even if the parent object is a constant object. Otherwise the `mutable` behavior wouldn't work.

Comment: @yxyc-137 No, the `this` pointer of a regular member function is not a const pointer. Many C++ textbooks incorrectly say what you're saying.(or you're saying what those books incorrectly say). The correct statement is the `this` pointer of a non-static non-const member function is `Class*` while the `this` pointer of a non-static const member function is `const X*`.

Answer (score 3):

> how does the compiler implement it?

Before asking how the compiler handles `mutable`, you should ask [how the compiler handles `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893220/how-is-const-implemented).

As the name implies, `mutable` is just another qualifier (or rather a [storage class specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)) that interacts with how `const` is handled. It simply means that a `mutable` member variable can be modified, even if the containing object is declared `const`. It can also be modified through a `const` reference (or pointer) to the containing object. It does not directly relate to member functions.

Note that a `mutable` member variable cannot be modifier through a direct `const` reference (or pointer).

When looking at a mutating operation on a symbol, the compiler simply checks whether the symbol can be mutated in this context according to the rules above.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/Mhx7YYf76):

```
struct S {
    mutable int i;
};

int main() {
    S const object{0};
    object.i = 1; // ok because object.i is qualified `mutable`, even if object is `const`
    S const& ref = object;
    ref.i = 2; // ok because ref refers to an object that has a `mutable` member `i`

    int const& direct_ref = object.i;
    direct_ref = 3; // error because direct_ref directly refers to a `const` symbol
}
```

Comment: Nice response to the question. It seems that OP doesn't understand what happens behind  the compile process, and your linked question explains it.